# React js click outside of the component does not work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component in my react s application where i use `ClickAwayListener` from `@mui/material/ClickAwayListener`.

```js
export default function MultipleSelectChip() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
      // On autofill we get a the stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {[1, 2, 3].map(() => {
        return (
          <div>
            <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => console.log("click outside")}>
              <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-chip-label">Chip</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-multiple-chip-label"
                  id="demo-multiple-chip"
                  multiple
                  value={personName}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  input={
                    <OutlinedInput id="select-multiple-chip" label="Chip" />
                  }
                  renderValue={(selected) => (
                    <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}>
                      {selected.map((value) => (
                        <Chip key={value} label={value} />
                      ))}
                    </Box>
                  )}
                  MenuProps={MenuProps}
                >
                  {names.map((name) => (
                    <MenuItem
                      key={name}
                      value={name}
                      style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
                    >
                      {name}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </ClickAwayListener>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expect to trigger `onClickAway` function only when i click outside a dropdown. But when i click the dropdown plus when i select an option the function also is triggered and i don't understand why. Hw to get the expected behaviour when click outside one of the dropdown? 
 NOTE: the functionality works if i don't use `map()`, meaning without many dropdowns. 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectchip-material-demo-forked-n03vq?file=/demo.js:1080-2905

Comment: Not working for me even after removing map, initially thought its due to key attribute but something else is causing this, maybe another props form mui document.